# Factorization: What went wrong with d?

Tags: python, for-loop, factorization

Consider:

[Enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EEiP8.png)

```
Input: 20
       17
       999997

Output: 2^2 * 5
        17
        757 * 1321
```

My code:

```
a = int(input())

# Find the factors first
for i in range(2, a+1):

    s = 0
    b = a
    d = 0

    # See if it is a prime number
    if a%i == 0:
        for x in range(1, i+1):
            if a%x == 0:
                d = d + x

        if (d-1)/i == 1:
            d = 0
            print(i)
        else:
            s = 0
            b = a
            d = 0

            continue

            d = 0

        # I will see how many prime numbers
        while(b>0):

            if (b/i)%1 == 0:
                s = s + 1
                b = b/i
            else:
                b = 0
                if b == 1:
                   b = 0

        print(s)
```

I will find the factors first, and then see if it is a prime number. If so, I will see how many prime numbers it is

> if i input 12, it outputs 2 2

[Enter link description here](https://zerojudge.tw/ShowThread?postid=23486&reply=0)

Comment: As a side note: please refrain from inserting blank lines after each line of code, it makes it much harder and unpleasant to read.

Comment: If your code doesn't do what you expect it to, please provide the output vs expected output. If you get an error, please provide the complete error traceback.

Comment: This script is running successfully, I think in `a=int(input("Enter no. here"))` you have not included any message so on executing you might be seeing as stucked.

Comment: @RanjeetSingh It isn't running successfully, it does find the first factor and associated exponent, but not the others

Comment: i dont know what is continue mean,i use it first time,when one loop go through,d become very strange

Comment: @蔡銘恩 The keyword `continue` ends the current loop iteration and goes to the next one. In simpler terms, it won't execute the code that comes after the `continue` and will go back to the top of the loop instead

Comment: @蔡銘恩 what is your expected output on 20 and what are you actually getting, can you share that as well?

Comment: @RanjeetSingh His expected output is `2 2 5`, and the script returns `2 2` instead (with newlines instead of spaces)

Comment: so anybody know what should i do?

Comment: @RanjeetSingh do you know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a = int(input("Enter a number:"))

for i in range(2, a + 1):
    if a % i != 0:
        continue

    # SETTING THE DEFAULT VALUES AT THE BEGINNING OF EVERY ITERATION OF THE LOOP
    s = 0
    b = a
    d = 0

    for x in range(1, i + 1):
        if b % x == 0:
            d = d + x

    if (d - 1) / i == 1:
        d = 0
        print(i)
    else:
        # s = 0 # NO LONGER NEEDED, AS WE RESET THEM AT THE BEGINNING OF THE LOOP
        # b = a
        # d = 0
        continue

    while b > 0:
        if (b / i) % 1 == 0:
            s = s + 1
            b = b / i
        else:
            b = 0
            if b == 1:
                b = 0

    print(s)
    a /= i**s # THIS LINE IS IMPORTANT
```

You were close. You forgot to set the default values at the beginning of every iteration of the loop, so they sometimes didn't have the right values ; and you should set `a` to a different value by dividing it by the factor you found (`i**s`, so `i` to the power of `s`).

As has been mentioned, your code also follows an odd coding style. I suggest you stop putting newlines between each statement, and start separating operators with spaces (example: `range(3+5)` is bad, `range(3 + 5)` is more readable)

Comment: can you please tell me what a /=i**s meaning

Comment: i have another question

Comment: my output is 2^2 * 5

Comment: but i will get 1 more *

Comment: become 2^2* 5 *

Comment: @蔡銘恩 `a /= i**s` is the equivalent to `a = a / i**s` ; and `i**s` is `i` to the power of `s`. I divided `a` by the value of the factor you found, so that we may find the next factors that make `a`'s prime factorization after having removed the one we already found. I find it hard to explain, but for example, here we found `2**2` for 20 ; so we divide 20 by 4, and we get 5. It's now 5 whose prime factorization we want and by finding it we'll find 20's factorization. Apologies for how complex this sounds.
There are much better implementations out there. Also, I don't get that new question.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you need the output of the following.

```
import math

a = int(input())
while (a % 2 == 0):
    print(2)
    a = int(a/2)
while (a % 3 == 0):
    print(3)
    a = int(a/3)
for i in range(5, math.ceil(math.sqrt(a)), 6):
    while (a % i == 0):
        print(i)
        a = int(a / i)
    while (a % (i + 2) == 0):
        print(i + 2)
        a = int(a / (i + 2))
if (a > 3):
    print(a)
```

This will give you the prime factors for a given number. As I can understand, it is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You are using too many loops here and that's why you are getting too much confused. Here is the code which serve the same purpose (if I understand your problem correctly)

```
a = int(input("Enter a number: "))
i = 2
factors = []
while i <= a:
    if (a%i) == 0:
        factors.append(i)
        a = a/i
    else:
        i = i + 1
print(factors)
```

here I am returning a list, if you want you can change the type accordingly.

Here are the inputs/outputs:

```
Enter a number: 17
[17]
```

```
Enter a number: 100
[2, 2, 5, 5]
```

```
Enter a number: 12
[2, 2, 3]
```